# Docker on the mac separates internal and external file ownerships; not so on linux

Tags: linux, docker, centos, volume, ownership

Running docker on the Mac, with a centos image, I see mounted volumes taking on the ownership of the centos (internal) user, while on the filesystem the ownership is mine (mdf:mdf).

Using the same centos image on RHEL 7, I see the volumes mounted, but inside, in centos, the home dir and the files all show my uid (1055).

I can do a recursive chown to, e.g., insideguy:insideguy, and all looks right. But back in the host filesystem, the ownerships have changed to some other person in the registry that has the same uid as was selected for insideguy(1001) when useradd was executed.

Is there some fundamental limitation in docker for Linux that makes this happen?

As another side effect, in our cluster one cannot chown on a mounted filesystem, even with sudo privileges; only on a local filesystem. So the desire to keep the docker home directories in, e.g., ~/dockerhome, fails because docker seems to be trying (and failing) to perform some chowns (not described in the Dockerfile or the start script, so assumed to be part of the --volume treatment). Placed in /var or /opt with appropriate ownerships, all goes well.

Any idea what's different between the two docker hosts?

Specifics: OSX 10.11.6; docker v1.12.1 on mac, v1.12.2 on RHEL 7; centos 7

Comment: I think this is related to the fact that Docker runs inside a VM on Mac, but runs directly on the host on RHEL

Answer (score 4):

There is a fundamental limitation to Docker on OS X that makes this happen: that is the fact that Docker only runs on Linux.

When running Docker on other platforms, this requires first setting up a Linux VM (historically through VirtualBox, although more recently other options are available) and then running Docker inside that VM.

Because Docker is running natively on Linux, it is sharing filesystems directly with the host when you use something like `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path`.  So if inside the container you run `chown userA somefile` and user A has userid 1001, and on your host that user id belongs to userB, then of course when you look at the files on the host they will appear to be owned by userB.  There's no magic here; this is just how Unix file permissions work.  You get the same behavior if, say, you were to move a disk or NFS filesystem from one host to another that had conflicting entries in their local `/etc/passwd` files.

Most Docker containers are running as `root` (or at least, not as your local user).  This means that any files created by a process in Docker will typically *not* be owned by you, which can of course cause problems if you are trying to access a filesystem that does not permit this sort of access.  Your choices when using Docker are pretty the same choices you have when not using Docker: either ensure that you are running containers as your own user id -- which may not be possible, since many images are built assuming they will be running as root -- or arrange to store files somewhere else.

This is one of the reasons why many people discourage the use of host volume mounts, because it can lead to this sort of confusion (and also because when interacting with a remote Docker API, the remote Docker daemon doesn't have any access to your local host filesystem).

With Docker for Mac, there is some magic file sharing that goes on to expose your local filesystem to the Linux VM (for example, with VirtualBox, Docker may use the [shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) feature).  This translation layer is probably the cause of the behavior you've noted on OS X with respect to file ownership.